# css erase all between { } sublime text

Tags: css, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

it is possible to clean the contents of a CSS file, leaving only the class names and @medias with search and replace tool?

for example:

this:

```
#id .class {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

leave it:

```
#id .class {

}
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You want to replace everything between `{` and `}` with a single empty line. The regular expression for this is

```
\{([^\}])+\}
^    ^     ^
{    |     }
     |
 anything that's not a `}`
```

The replacement is `{\n\n}`.

#### Screenshot

[image: Replacement term]

Comment: Good response, your code, erase all content in my @medias, but i can todo this on separate file.
Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Emmet installed you can use `Control` + `D`. That will "Select Between Container" (You might have to press it multiple times depending on where your cursor starts).

There's also `Control` + `Shift` + `Space` that will do it all in one shot no matter where the cursor is.

I listed `Control` + `D` first because I find it a lot more useful.

I found an awesome article with a lot of nice shortcuts here: 
https://viget.com/extend/my-overused-sublime-text-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Just reread your question. Leaving this here in case it helps someone anyway. Up voted the other answer.